Как восстановить доступ к базе данных?
после переустановки системы и смены имени пользователя не получается подключить базу данных к проекту.


Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Папки профилей пользователя защищены правами файловой системы ntfs. Переложи файл туда, где он доступен текущему пользователю.

Переместил в корень D диска, такая же ошибка выходит

@Jorj9872, возможно, файл сохранил права доступа - проверь в свойствах.
